# Compiling NDK via macosx terminal and getting #createnativelibrary

Tags: macos, compilation, android-ndk

I was sent a build to compile for NDK apps, and I keep getting this error while running

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

in terminal on mac:

```
[A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 > Exception thrown while executing model rule: NdkComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createNativeLibrary
  > Exception thrown while executing model rule: NdkComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createNativeLibrary > create(app_jni)
  > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue was reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200553

Sounds like you need to set the `ndk.dir` variable in your local.properties file to the correct NDK path.